# How to get a dataset from GitHub?

Tags: import, dataset

I want to use the dataset on https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/data

And the dataset is published on GitHub at the following address.

https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset

I want to Classify all the data with Mathematica.

and I would like to predict what shape the randomly drawn picture is.

I want to know how to import GitHub's dataset from Mathematica.

How to get a dataset from GitHub?

Comment: If you click on the green "Code" button, you'll get a URL along with the options of using Git or subversion to clone the repository. You also have the option of downloading the zip file. Mathematica includes the GitLink package, which allows you to use git to clone the repository within Mathematica, though you'll have to install git yourself. The accompanying GitLink page describes use of the GitClone command.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful!